# ActiveRecord Includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, performance, activerecord

I have made a workout application with with the following models:

user 
routine 
lifts
exercises
infos

A routine belongs to a user
A routine has many lifts (which is a joins between exercise and routine)

A lift belongs to an exercise
Infos(sets) belong to a lift

I am digging into ActiveRecord Queries and specifically includes to work on the n+1 problems I am having.  When I show the entire routine which shows:

The routines name
The users name
The exercise names for each lift
The sets for each lift

If I want to make less queries can I simply load up everything such as in the following:
a = Routine.includes(:user, :lifts, :exercises, :infos) and loop through all of that to find what I want?

Or do I have to break it down more say:
a = Routine.includes(:user, :lifts)
b = Lift.includes(:exercise, :infos)
in order to shrink the amount of queries I have.

If this question is not clear enough please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work. `Routine.includes(:user, {:lifts => [:exercise, :infos]})`

Comment: Would you be able to explain what this is?  To me it looks like it will load all the routines, the associated users, and every lifts' exercise and infos.

Comment: There is way too much for me to explain, but there is plenty of info on the web. You should read through this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html