# One db query on associative models ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

I am using Ruby on Rails. In my file sharing application I have a model structure that looks like this:

```
User has many Entities
Entity belongs to User
Entity has many Reports
Report belongs to Entity
Report has many Shares
Share belongs to Report
```

Now when I have a share_id, how can I extract the User, Entity and Report information for that share_id in one db query? And is it better to do 3 simple queries or one complex join-type query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) like this should work:

```
Share.includes(report: { entity: :user }).find(share_id)
```

see also this question: [ActiveRecord Includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108371/activerecord-includes)

**Update**
Apparently the correct API for what you need is [`eager_load`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/eager_load)

```
Share.eager_load(report: { entity: :user }).find(share_id)
```

Comment: This will still perform 4 queries, sadly. I thought `includes` was meant to perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but it simply performs separate queries for each relation, mainly used to avoid N+1 queries. Only way I can see to do this with a single query is via `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and alias columns such as `report_column`, `entity_column`, `user_column`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @DamienRoche I was surprised at that, but I've updated with the correct API

Comment: I have been playing with eager_load today. Looks very promising indeed but I am getting stuck with it. When I look at the generated sql statement all looks well and the result includes results from all four tables. However when I read the eager_load into a variable like `@all = Share.eager_load(report: { entity: :user }).find(share_id)`, then @all only has the results of a Share object. How can I get access to the results of the other tables?

Comment: You mean like `@reports = @all.map(&:report)`?

Comment: Yes thats it! But I get an error when using it just like that: undefined method `map' for #<Share:0xb372f408>

Comment: @hec - my bad - `find` returns a single instance, so `@all` is actually `@share`, and then `@report = @share.report`, and `@entity = @report.entity`, and `@user = @entity.user`...

Comment: Alrighty, the only and best way to do it then is with 4 queries to the db?

Comment: No - there should be no query to the db - they are already loaded.